# VMWare Player presses and holds random keys

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I am running Windows 8 and VMWare Player with a bunch of VM ranging from Windows, to various flavors of Linux.

The issue that I am having is that what seems like every 2 minutes, or when I switch between VM's or back into windows - VMWare player will press and hold either my Right Alt key, or the letter 'c', and just continually span the VM until I physically press that key on my keyboard.

I have looked up adding a line to the .vmx file that prevents repeated keypresses, but obviously this is not helping.

Has anyone ever experienced an issue similar to this? And what can I do to fix it? I have put up with it for far too long.

If no solutions, how can I convert my VMWare machines to a visualization technology that does not have issues like this?

Comment: How are you switching between the client VMs and the host machine? Do you use CTRL+ALT / CTRL+g or just use the mouse? What make is our keyboard (I have occasional issues with repeating keys with my Cherry keyboard, though not associated with VMs).

Comment: I always switch using the mouse, minimizing from the toolbar. I am using the keyboard that is part of my Dell Latitude e6520, also does it with an external Apple keyboard.

Comment: I am going to try and use Workstation for a bit and see if that solves any issues.